# Convert Json to list and dictionary

Tags: c#, json

How to convert json to list and dictionary in C# recursively it child (like python).

Example

```
{"array1":
[
    object1:
    {
        "property1": "value1",
        "property2": "value2"
    }
]}
```

After convert I have an array name array1. array1[0] return a dictionary.
array1[0]["property1"] return "value1".

I want to do it recursively. Because I dont know structure of this json.

Comment: If you don't know the structure of the JSON how do you know it's a dictionary?

Comment: Your data isn't actually a valid JSON object. Is this a typo or do you get data like this?

Comment: I have worked with pythone. With python, I dont need a class and mapping json to create a object. I just create an object and use it as a List or dict.

Answer (score -1):

if you dont know structure of this json.
use json.net jsonpath

[enter link description here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/search.html?SearchText=jsonpath)